# In HTTP, is a query allowed when only giving a path as Request-URI?

Tags: http, curl, httprequest, uri

I am having a problem implementing a simple web server. According to the spec, a [HTTP/1.1 request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) starts with this line:

```
Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

In this line, there is a `Request-URI` which is defined as follows:

```
Request-URI    = "*" | absoluteURI | abs_path | authority
```

So, I am allowed to either send a complete URI (with schema, server name, etc) or an `abs_path` (`authority` is, as defined in the spec, only for the `CONNECT` method). Then I have:

```
abs_path      = "/"  path_segments
path_segments = segment *( "/" segment )
```

These definitions are from the [URI spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), which is linked in the HTTP spec. As we see, `abs_path` is only an absolute path *without* the query.

So far the theory. Now when I actually send a HTTP GET request to `http://example.com/?key=value`, this line is sent:

```
GET /?key=value HTTP/1.1
```

I tried this using Firefox, Chrome and `curl`. Shouldn't that be illegal according to the spec? Am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're looking at an outdated version of the spec.

See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#origin-form for the correct ABNF.

Comment: Thanks. Since I don't know who or what greenbytes is, I checked the [IETF version of that RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.3.1), which says the same.

Answer (score 2):

That is a known error in RFC 2616:

- [Errata ID: 3056](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=2616) and the corresponding fix: [Changeset 76](https://trac.ietf.org/trac/httpbis/changeset/76)
- [HTTP/1.1 Specification Errata: URI includes query](http://purl.org/NET/http-errata#uriquery) / [RFC2616bis Issues: URI includes query](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616bis/issues/#i11)
- [Errata: HTTP URL abs_path should include query](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg-old/2001MayAug/0034.html)

RFC 7230, which obsoletes RFC 2616, allows it. Its definition of [`request-line`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) uses [`request-target`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) (instead of `Request-URI`), which allows [`origin-form`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1) (instead of `abs_path`):

> ```
> origin-form    = absolute-path [ "?" query ]
> ```